# Simple Communication between Objects NSNotification/Delegates or similar?

Tags: objective-c, opencv, delegates, nsnotifications

I just started with Objective C and have a question concerning communication between two objects.

Say I have an Object, let's call it **aTimcode** instantiated from main() from class "Timecode" which is a class that stores a Timecode (01:30:20:10 for example) and has methods to de/increase this timecode and some more methods that do math with Timecodes.

I have a second Object, lets call it **aVideo** from Class "Video" that does some (openCV) stuff on a video, also created in main().

so my main() looks like:

```
Timecode *aTimecode = [[Timecode alloc] init];
Video    *aVideo    = [[Video alloc] init];
[aVideo doFancyOpenCVSTUFF: someparameter];
```

I now want **aVideo** to call methods on **aTimecode**. something like

```
[aTimecode increaseFramesBy: 5];
```

I know the easy way to establish communication would be to instantiate aTimecode from within aVideo with:

```
// somewhere within aVideo

Timecode * aTimceode = [[Timecode alloc] init];
[aTimecode increaseFramesBy: 5];
[aTimecode release];
```

but of course this will destroy the information stored in aTimecode when its released.

but when the program goes further I want a lot of Video objects (**bVideo**, **cVideo**, etc...) to contribute to the values in **aTimecode** and do math with the previously stored numbers. **aTimecode** should store them even when aVideo gets released and bVideo starts doing some stuff.

What's the right way to communicate? Delegates? NSNotification?

There could be the situation that for example **aVideo** sends a lot of messages to **aTimecode** - 10 times a second or more often. What's the right way for sending so many messages in short time?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it would seem simplest to create an `initWithTimecode:` method in the `Video` class.

This assumes that the `Video` uses `Timecode` methods as opposed to methods that might be part of `Timecode` or might be part of something else.  If that's wrong and you need to pass in various object types, then you would use a protocol and a delegate.

Notifications would be more appropriate if the `Video` is just declaring that certain events have happened and doesn't care whether any other object (or many) is taking notice of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Timecode object not necessarily has to be released if it is a parameter of a certain Video object. You might want to create a singleton class that keeps the Timecode object in it and pass a weak reference to it to all the created Video objects, after that you can either use KVO, NSNotifications or delegates, whichever you prefer the most. Delegation, though, would seem to be the clearest solution here.

Comment: @Philip Mills - Thanks for the ultra quick and very very helpful answers!!! Will try with initwithTimecode first.